# With new Audio(), is there any way to find out of the audio file exists?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

Is there any way to find out if an audio file exists from the initialized Audio instance?

For example, if I try to compare an existing audio and a non-existing audio file:

```
new Audio('exists.mp3').readyState           => 0

new Audio('does_not_exist.mp3').readyState   => 0
(HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://amc.narom.no/Steid failed.)
```

The return value is the same, but the console logs the error of not being able to load the media resource. Is there a way to catch this message, or using any method within the Audio object to find out whether the audio file exists or not?

Note:
I know I can do a HttpRequest or AJAX request to the source of the audio to check if it exists, but was wondering if this could be done in a more effective way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not synchronously, so immediately accessing a property will not work as you must wait for the browser to attempt the network request, but yes, you can use the `error` and `loadeddata` events (optionally substituting other similar media events to determine success) .

```
var a = new Audio('doesitexist.mp3');
a.onerror = function() {
    console.log('File does not exist.');
};
a.onloadeddata = function() {
    console.log('File exists.');
};
```

The `loadeddata` event will not fire until at least some data has successfully been loaded, and `error` will fire if the request returned an invalid response like a 404 error.